# Can't see the date value from a <td> element in Date1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to compare two dates that are being pulled from a database. I am doing this all in ASP .NET mvc.

Here is my Model class:

```
public DateTime? Date1{ get; set; }
public DateTime? Date2 { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult 
   {
      Hello test = new Hello();
      return View(test.getStuff());
    }
```

Views:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
    <td id="date1"> @Html.EditorFor(x => item.Date1)</td>
    <td id="date2">@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Date2)</td>
   }

   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("td#date1").bind("change", function () {
            var cur_td = $(this).parent("tr#home");
            var date2 = cur_td.find("td#date2").text();
            console.log(date2);
            var date1 = cur_td.find("td#date1").text(); // I don't understand why this is null? 
            console.log(date1);

            if (date1 > date2) {
                alert("Outside of the Editor Box");
            } else {
                alert("Date ok");
            }
     });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field date1 must be a date." id="item_date1" name="item.Date1" type="date" value="2017-03-31">

<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field date1 must be a date." id="item_date1" name="item.Date1" type="date" value="2017-04-20">
```

This is what the console of Google chrome spits out: 
Console:

[image: Console]

**Date2** is shown, but **Date1** remains blank, so the if statement is always skipping the first condition and goes straight to the else condition. I just want to compare these two dates, but I can't seem to get the date value for **Date1**. Any work around for this?

Comment: Please show your html.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I realize that, only date1 needs to be edited. Is the .Editorfor function causing these problems?

Comment: You have a @foreach loop, and inside of it, you render your td tags. You are using ID's date1 and date2 inside your foreach, that means that for each loop you will get several td tags with the same ID, that is a bad idea, you will not be able to tell wich td you really want.

Comment: @PoulBak uploaded the HTML.

Comment: @AlfredoA. I see the problem, what is a work around for this? I am fetching all of these dates by querying from a DB. How can I pull it out of the loop and still have the dates I need?

Comment: You can search your items relative to a parent, e.g., relative to the associated tr tag (which should have a unique ID). Also, check your css selectors, you are selecting 'td#date1' but your html generated code uses 'item_date1' as an ID. This is due to the way you are generating them ---> @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Date1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code. First of all, you have hardcoded `Id` attribute values inside the foreach loop, which will create same Id value for more than one element.

Since you have multiple items you are rendering inside a loop, you should consider using relative methods like `closest` and `find`. I would also wrap the tds inside a parent element which you can use to limit the scope when using the relative methods.

I removed the `Id` attribute and gave a simple date1 and date2 attribute to each tds

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td date1> @Html.EditorFor(x => item.Date1)</td>
            <td date2>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Date2)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Now in your script, you can use this attribute to listen to the change event in the `input` element, use the 2 date values, create `Date` objects from those strings and do the check.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("td[date1] > input").bind("change", function () {

        var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var date1 = $(this).val();
        var date2 = $tr.find("td[date2]").text();

        // Make sure to check date1 and date2 for empty string before trying to parse

        var d1 = Date.parse(date1);
        var d2 = Date.parse(date2);

        if (d1 > d2) {
            console.log("Outside of the Editor Box");
        } else {
            console.log("Date ok");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: that worked like a charm! However one question, If I would like the textbox to return to its original date after returning "Outside the box" how would that be possible?

Comment: `$(this).val("any value you want")`

Comment: I tried that, $(this).val(date1), but it gives me the date I selected, not the original date I initially had in the editorbox.